# Use DrawerLayout Back Button to Return to Previous Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

I have successfully set up a navigation drawer utilizing the drawer layout. I have found that removing this simple line of code changes the hamburger icon to a back button:

```
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

However, when I click the back button it is still opening the navigation drawer when indeed I want to return to the previous activity.

I know I could simply set an `onClickListener`, but I figured Android had a more native way of navigating to the previous screen. Here is my code:'

**onCreate():**

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            toolbar,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        /**
         * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
         */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            isOpen = false;
        }

        /**
         * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
         */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            isOpen = true;
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    ArrayList<String> drawerTitleArray = new ArrayList<>();
    drawerTitleArray.add(0, "TEST");
    drawerTitleArray.add(1, "TEST 1");
    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerTitleArray));
```

Other:

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `onOptionsItemSelected()` of drawer activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I do not believe this will work as there is not a return statement in the "if" portion of the conditional

Comment: Correct, I edited my code. `true` since we are consuming the event.

Comment: Not the solution, it is still opening the nav drawer

Comment: Snap...can you debug and check if the click event for 'back button' is actually resulting in `onBackPressed()` call above (just in case its being consumed elsewhere)?